# How can I get my div height to match the dynamic image height?

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow that scales with the width of the page, and a navbar below it.  However when the page gets too wide the images cover the navbar.  How can I scale the size of the div so that the navbar sticks to the image no matter how wide the screen is?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ba9z8/

CSS:

```
 div.sitenavbar {
     width:100%; 
     background: #333366; 
     height:55px; 
     text-align:center;}
 #slideshow {
     position:relative;
     height:250px;
     width:100%;
 }

 #slideshow IMG {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;
     z-index:8; 
     width:100%;
 }

 #slideshow IMG.active {
     z-index:10;
 }

 #slideshow IMG.last-active {
     z-index:9;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="slideshow">
     <img src="https://mylinguistica.com/assets/img/slide1.png" alt="" class="active" />
     <img src="https://mylinguistica.com/assets/img/slides2.png" alt="" />
     <img src="https://mylinguistica.com/assets/img/slides3.png" alt="" />
 </div>
 <div class="sitenavbar">
 test
 </div>
```

Comment: You forgot to press the "Tidy up" button in jsFiddle -.- Also, your demo throws an error. Pass a reference to the function to setTimeout, not a string.

Comment: I would suggest the use of some JavaScript. After the `img.src` has been set, you can query the `img` object for `naturalHeight`, `naturalWidth`, `offsetHeight`, and `offsetWidth`. You can then size your navbar appropriately. I'm not posting this as an answer because, unfortunately, this does not seem to work in every browser. In chrome, for example, the value I just described will still come back as `0` even after the `img.src` has been set. There has to be an easier way to do this. I hope someone provides you with a great answer, as I am asking this question myself.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Who ever presses the "Tidy Up" button anyway?

Comment: and its `setInterval` by the way. But hes right, it should look like this: `setInterval(slideSwitch, 5000);` [**I updated your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ba9z8/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle tips.

Comment: @WebWanderer Uhm… smart people? :P

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a way to do this with javascript.  I took the ratio of the image height to width and then adjusted the div based on the width of the window:

```
       $(document).ready(function() {
            var bodyheight = $(document).width();
            bodyheight = bodyheight * .198;
            $("#slideshow").height(bodyheight);
        });

        // for the window resize
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var bodyheight = $(document).width();
            bodyheight = bodyheight * .198;
            $("#slideshow").height(bodyheight);
```

In my case the image was 1000x198px, so the ration is .198.